# How to use multipule functions for this?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I want to have a function and a input work together to create something like this:

```
import time, sys

def sprint(s):

    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

This last code is what I want to get to work. I want it to take input while performing the sprint function:

```
pas=input(sprint("LOGIN: ")
```

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what you exactly want?

Comment: Could you show us the `input()` method?

Comment: @KirtimanSinha `input` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're looking for. There's an easy way to get around your problem.

```
import time
import sys

def sprint(s):
  for c in s:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)

pas = sprint("LOGIN: ")
pas = input("")
```

It will act exactly the same way as before too. All I did was separate the `sprint` and `input` because they cannot coexist. However, doing `sprint` and THEN asking for `input` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is bizarre (the one proposed by Johnny is better), but if you insist on it, make your function return an empty string that would be used as a parameter to `input()`:

```
def sprint(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    return ""
```